# Cancel derivative

Tags: calculus

I know partial derivative cannot be canceled but what about total derivative? Is it always true that $\frac{dz}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{dz}{dx}$--of course in this case expression of $z(y)$ depends on $y$ alone and does not involve $x$. I checked limit definition and am confident this is true. But my calculus teacher cautioned against this practice saying it is not "rigorous". So I figured I better have some confirmation here if I missed anything.

Comment: This is just the chain rule from single variable calculus. There is no 'cancellation', it's just how the rule works.

Comment: @PeterForeman oh yes..